# IIS force asking for certificate to a client node.js application

Tags: ssl, iis, https, certificate

I have an application running on IIS 8.5 on my Windows Server 2012 and I have configured it to use [this](https://www.mrdomain.com/products/ssl/dondominio-domain-ssl/) certificate I just bought. So now I can access the website using https protocol.

I have node.js clients running on some computers outside my network and posting some data to the server from time to time. I want to secure that connection now that I have a SSL certificate. I've been googling around for a couple of hours and I was not able to have the picture of what I need to do.

My goal would be to do the HTTP POST from client and only the clients using the certificate would be allowed to upload data to my https://example.com/upload url.

Firstly, I need to configure IIS so that requires a certificate when doing the handshake but I have no option for that in the authentication panel inside my webapp. I only have these options:
 [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Click on SSL Settings**

[image: Click on SSL Settings]

**Then tick Require SSL**

[image: Then tick Require SSL]